# Fill holes in Brick & Mortar

Tags: brick, mortar

There are a couple of holes in my brick and mortar that I'd like to fill.

Will this work for the mortar ?

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000H5SDH0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000H5SDH0)

What could I use to fill the holes ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I’ve read you can take an extra brick and basically break it up into dust and add that to the mortar to tint it to the brick color.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.